# Couldn't find Post with 'id'=params[:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

If I don’t have row with `id=params[:id]` how can i check it, since 
when I write

```
def show
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    if @post.nil?
       @post={
        title:"No such post",
        post:"No such post"
       }
    end
end
```

I get error.

Comment: What error do you get? The code looks ok to me.

Comment: That is on purpose. You should handle missing pages with 404.html or in controller. Why do you want to display a specific page when post is not found?

Comment: For me too;but I get error for my @post=Post.find(params[:id]);so I can`t check is my @post false or true

Comment: how can I write my 404.html;where should I put it

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find):

> **find(*args)**
>
> Find by id - This can either be a specific id (1), a list of ids (1, 5, 6), or an array of ids ([5, 6, 10]). If no record can be found for all of the listed ids, then RecordNotFound will be raised.

So if `find` can't find anything with the `id` you're looking for, it raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception rather than return `nil` like you want it to. That exception ends up being handled deep inside Rails and gets converted to a 404.

You could trap that exception yourself:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @post = {
    title: "No such post",
    post: "No such post"
  }
end
```

Note that you'd only trap the specific exception you're expecting to see, a bare `rescue` is almost always a mistake because it can hide bugs.

You could also use [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by):

> **find_by(*args)**
>   [...]
>   If no record is found, returns `nil`.

like this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by(:id => params[:id])
  if @post.nil?
    @post = {
      title: "No such post",
      post: "No such post"
    }
  end
end
```

Exceptions are meant for handling errors and other exceptional conditions, they're not meant to be used for normal flow control. I'd probably use `find_by` for this sort of thing; it seems that you're expecting the occasional missing record so it a missing record isn't really an error or an unexpected condition.

Answer (score 1):

`show` controller is expected to show existing elements only. When an element (`Post` instance) does not exist, `find` throws an exception. As @Michal suggested in the comments, usually non-existing entities are being handled with `404` response, or like.

For the time, being, though, you might cheat Rails with:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id]) rescue { 
    title: "No such post",
    post: "No such post"
  }
```

This is not a production solution, of course, but it might help during learning phase.

Comment: Thanks;so it like "try{} except{}" statements in other languages;